# PHP writing contents of a web page to a file. Encoding is seems to be wrong though

Tags: php, encoding, zend-framework2, notepad++

I have a problem that uses the Zend\Http\Client to retrieve the body of a web page.  It then writes the body to a file.  When I open the file in Firefox and it detects the encoding as UTF-8, it displays fine.  When I open the file up in Notepad++ it detects the encoding as "ANSI as UTF-8" and shows little boxes here and there.

Why is that happening and is there a way to make the boxes go away?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried opening it other things? Do they do the same with the little boxes?

Comment: In notepad it shows okay, in Wordpad it shows weird characters (â€)

Comment: Perhaps its a Notpad++ setting then. The file is what it is, if it works in Notepad then its contents is OK.

Comment: Just to be a bit more clear also.  The ultimate place I want this content to go is into a SQLite database (which is only UTF-8).  When I do that right now, I get weird characters and question marks in my sqlite data.

Comment: Also, when running the program from the command line and echo-ing out the content, I get question marks in the windows command line.

Comment: When it runs good in some but not in other apps, then why not just try your real destination and see if it works there? Editors and encoding is something pretty funny at times.

Comment: Because my real destination is my SQLite database, and it doesn't display correctly when placed in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php before inserting into the database.

iconv has helped me in the past when characters haven't been behaving as expected.

You may also want to try directly saving the source of the page in question. This might help determine if in fact the issue is with Zend's helper.

You could also test using cURL and file_get_conents.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I've tried file_get_contents and the same result happens.  I've also tried iconv, but it requires that you know what you are converting from.  I tried converting from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, and that just made even more weird characters. :-/